# trouble installing object aid in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, objectaid

I have installed the object aid in my eclipse but when I want to create the diagram, I cannot click the finish button like this. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: can you add the error message, so you could get help faster

Answer (score 0):

The only one i found was to go back to an Eclipse <= 4.19